# Windows app manifest or winapi call to block recording by Xbox App and others?

Tags: winapi, manifest

**Edit: See Answer and comments below.  If you think this is a low-quality question that should be deleted, please post a comment to explain why**

Microsoft offers an Xbox App for Windows 10 desktop that includes screen capture and screen recording of Windows applications.

According to Lifehacker.com, "while a few applications can exempt themselves, most have not. ...  The Game Bar won’t record Skype for Desktop, for example."

This might be hard-wired into the Xbox app, but I'm hoping there is some new, undocumented application manifest entry or entries covering "privacy" or "recording" or similar, or a Win32 or COM call, and that someone here can provide details.

Comment: There's [SetWindowDisplayAffinity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375340.aspx).

Comment: I'm surprised by the downvote.  I've been writing WIn32 code since 1996 and can't recall seeing  SetWindowDisplayAffinity mentioned before,  A Google and SO search did not turn it up based on other keywords.  Thanks  @IInspectable

Comment: This API function was introduced in Windows 7, and is not exactly one that's in frequent use either.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @IInspectable for pointing me to the right WIn32 function: SetWindowDisplayAffinity.  I'm answering in more detail for anyone else who runs into this.

```
SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hWnd, WDA_MONITOR); // hWnd is app main window
```

If you add this to your code after creating your application's main window then programs using standard Windows APIs to capture screens and video will still run, but the results will be an image that is all black pixels.

This only works if the Desktop Window Manager is running, see Raymond Chen's blog of June 3, 2013 for a little more detail - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130603-00/?p=4193

This will not stop IAccessible accessibility code from working, though it will break at least some older screen magnifier apps.